# Unity not working properly after a crash

Tags: unity, 15.10, launcher, display, display-resolution

I had a graphics GUI crash where everything worked (my spotify was still playing, the stuff was moving in the game I was playing at the time and my mouse moved) except clicking and keyboard input (the mouse moved but I couldnt click anything, despite the fact that it seemed everything else was working).

After restarting, I found all of my unity settings got reset (my launcher icons, display settings are all back to default), and when I change them they all get reset back after restarting. With my graphics settings, half of them dont work (I cant turn off stiky edges (which I despise) and menu scaling, launcher placement doesnt work (it reflects the changes in the menu but doesnt do anything, and all these settings reset after restart).

Other display settings (resolution, rotation, turning screens on and off mirroring options) work as expected.

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something completely messed up !

The re-install of the desktop environment should fix it.

Open a terminal and execute the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

After the installation I recommend to restart the system.

Comment: Didn't work, everything still gets reset after restart and display settings still dont work :(

Comment: There must be more messed up as assumed ... as you reinstalled the whole desktop environment, the complete reinstallation of the operating system would be the next and most promising solution. :)

Comment: Would there be a way to do that without losing my files and stuff (I have my /home folder mounted to a different partition from my OS, that might make it easier)

Comment: @user1830386 : When you do not format the /home partition you will not loose your personal data and files, but I recommend to back it up to another disk nevertheless before re-installing the Ubuntu system. :)